# Windows Server 2019 Backup includes Hyper-V checkpoints

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-backup, windows-server-2019

I've noticed two issues on Windows Server 2019, when creating backups with the build in Windows Server Backup feature.

Apparently my virtual machines are being put into a backup or create checkpoint state:

[image: Hyper-v manager]

This process often doesn't complete. Which causes issues when restarting the server, as the system becomes stuck on stopping the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service.

As a workaround I've tried excluding Hyper-V from the backup. Which brings me to my 2nd issue.
I've specifically unchecked Hyper-V including the sub components (Host component and the individual virtual machines) from the Windows Server Backup, yet somehow the virtual machines are still being backed up..

Is there any fix for either one of these issues?

Comment: Try to change Checkpoint from "production" to "standard" in Hyper-V VM configuration. Moreover, you may try to use Veeam or Nakivo/Altaro as alternative and more efficient backup solutions for Hyper-V.